# SpSecutityTrimmedControl runs in Pagepreview mode - ?pagepreview=true

Tags: 2010, security, branding, security-trimming

I'm branding the sharepoint ribbon and need some changes (css) when the page gets in pagepreview mode.

I've got this code

```
<SharePoint:SpSecutirtyTrimmedControl runat="server" ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControlRibbon" PermissionString="BrowseDirectories" PermissionMode="Any">
    <Common:ScriptCssLink DebugLink="/Style%20Library/css/editor.css" Link="/Style%20Library/css/editor.css" runat="server"/>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Why does this css loads when the site is in PagePreview mode -  ex http//test.com?pagepreview=true

Answer (score 1):

The security trimmed control only "trims" based on permissions. The page preview mode runs with the same user and therefore the same permissions so it will make no difference.

I solved such an issue by creating a custom control that rendered only if the query string contained PagePreview. You might try something like that.